# How can I vectorize this specific non-numpy function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Docstrings make the post look longer than it actually is. Also, my question is regarding a function at the top of a chain of function calls.

**The part that works:**

I would like to make a contour plot of chi squared values for a specified distribution. I understand the basics of how to make a contour plot work, but am unable to apply the techniques outside of basic examples. The problem may lie in vectorizing my functions. As a sample, consider a sample Gaussian dataset of 1000 points, the average and spread of which are 48 and 7, respectively.

```
# imports: import numpy as np, import random, from math import pi, from scipy.integrate import quad, from scipy.stats import chisquare, from scipy.optimize import minimize

dataset_gauss = [random.gauss(48, 7) for index in range(1000)]
```

My functions and variable names are the way they are because my full code takes multiple distributions (gaussian, lognormal)

```
def equation_gauss(x, a, b):
    """
    This function returns the equation for the Gaussian distribution.
    """
    cnorm = 1 / (b* (2*pi)**(1/2))
    return cnorm * np.exp((-1) * (x - a)**2 / (2* b**2))
```

Using maximum log-likelihood, my script (not relevant to question, so code not shown) returns `params_gauss = [47.972906400237889, 7.0241339595841286]`.

In order to calculate chi square, one must first make a list of bin bounds. Then one can equate each expectation value to the integral of the distribution equation from a bins left side to its right side for each bin. The observed values of each bin are the number of observed values within that bin. One can calculate chi square by summing the quotients of the square differences of the expected and observed values per bin divided by the expected values.

```
def get_bins(distribution, num_bins=50):
    """
    This function returns a specified number of equally sized bins over
    the domain of the distribution.
    """
    if distribution == 'gauss':
        dataset = dataset_gauss
    return np.linspace(min(dataset), max(dataset), num_bins)

def get_binned_expectations(distribution, args):
    """
    This function returns the expectation values per bin for a dataset
    given by the specified distribution.
    """
    if distribution == 'gauss':
        dataset = dataset_gauss
        func = equation_gauss
    num_obs = len(dataset)
    bins = get_bins(distribution)
    res = []
    for idx in range(len(bins)):
        if idx != len(bins)-1:
            res.append(quad(func, bins[idx] , bins[idx+1], args = (args[0] , args[1]))[0] * num_obs)
    return res

def get_binned_observations(distribution):
    """
    This function returns the observation values per bin for a dataset
    given by the specified distribution.
    """
    if distribution == 'gauss':
        dataset = dataset_gauss
    bins = get_bins(distribution)
    bin_count = []
    for idx in range(len(bins)):
        if idx != len(bins)-1:
            summ = 0
            for datum in dataset:
                if datum > bins[idx] and datum <= bins[idx+1]:
                    summ += 1
            bin_count.append(summ)
        if idx == len(bins)-1:
            pass
    return bin_count

def get_chi_square(distribution, params):
    """
    This function returns the chi square value for a specified
    distribution.

    EX:
        distribution    :   'gauss', 'lognormal'

        params          :   [a, b] for parameters a and b
                            'opt' (for optimized parameters)
    """
    values_observation = get_binned_observations(distribution)
    if params == 'opt':
        if distribution == 'gauss':
            params = params_gauss
    values_expectation = get_binned_expectations(distribution, params)
    return chisquare(values_observation, values_expectation)
```

As a check, let's try:

```
res = get_chi_square('gauss', params='opt')
print(res)
new_params = [40, 10]
new_res = get_chi_square('gauss', params=new_params)
print(new_res)

>> Power_divergenceResult(statistic=55.465132812431413, pvalue=0.21391356257718666)
>> Power_divergenceResult(statistic=14950.604250041084, pvalue=0.0)
```

The first value `statistic` is the chi squared value obtained with the corresponding parameters, while the second value `pvalue` is the probability of the  parameters fit. For my purposes, it's best to call only the first element as     `print(new_res[0])`. (The probabilities aren't very accurate as the degrees of freedom have not been specified).

In order to make a contour plot, my understanding is that I need to generate a grid space via dim-2 arrays. First, I write a function to return a list of numbers for each parameter. This is the function that returns `x, y` such that `X, Y` are its `meshgrid`.

```
def get_axis_data(param, frac, size):
    """
    This function returns a specified number of elements in a range
    centered around the value of the inputted parameter. The extrema
    of this range are specified as:
                    param ± param * frac
    """
    update = frac * param
    return np.linspace(param - update, param + update, size)
```

**My problem:**

I know that I can use `plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap)`. But, I do not know how to format `get_chi_square` to receive the `meshgrid`-ed parameters as inputs since it calls the scipy module to (efficiently) calculate chi square via a **list** of optimizable parameters. I've commented out the things that I've tried unsuccessfully.

```
def get_grid_data(distribution, frac=1/4, size=9, func=get_chi_square, cmap='plasma'):
    """
    This function returns the grid values for a contour plot of the
    error metric as a function of the parameters of a specified
    distribution.

    EX:
        func:   'chi square', 'maximum log-likelihood' (error metric)
    """
    if distribution == 'gauss':
        opt_params = params_gauss
    a_vals = get_axis_data(opt_params[0], frac, size)
    b_vals = get_axis_data(opt_params[1], frac, size)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(a_vals, b_vals)
    # func = np.vectorize(func)
    # Z = func(distribution, [X, Y])[0]
    return X, Y#, Z

X, Y = get_grid_data('gauss')
print("X")
print(X)
print("")
print("Y")
print(Y)
```

Running the above gives:

```
 X
[[ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]
 [ 35.9796798   38.97798645  41.9762931   44.97459975  47.9729064
   50.97121305  53.9695197   56.96782635  59.966133  ]]

Y
[[ 5.26810047  5.26810047  5.26810047  5.26810047  5.26810047  5.26810047
   5.26810047  5.26810047  5.26810047]
 [ 5.70710884  5.70710884  5.70710884  5.70710884  5.70710884  5.70710884
   5.70710884  5.70710884  5.70710884]
 [ 6.14611721  6.14611721  6.14611721  6.14611721  6.14611721  6.14611721
   6.14611721  6.14611721  6.14611721]
 [ 6.58512559  6.58512559  6.58512559  6.58512559  6.58512559  6.58512559
   6.58512559  6.58512559  6.58512559]
 [ 7.02413396  7.02413396  7.02413396  7.02413396  7.02413396  7.02413396
   7.02413396  7.02413396  7.02413396]
 [ 7.46314233  7.46314233  7.46314233  7.46314233  7.46314233  7.46314233
   7.46314233  7.46314233  7.46314233]
 [ 7.9021507   7.9021507   7.9021507   7.9021507   7.9021507   7.9021507
   7.9021507   7.9021507   7.9021507 ]
 [ 8.34115908  8.34115908  8.34115908  8.34115908  8.34115908  8.34115908
   8.34115908  8.34115908  8.34115908]
 [ 8.78016745  8.78016745  8.78016745  8.78016745  8.78016745  8.78016745
   8.78016745  8.78016745  8.78016745]]
```

I would like to print `Z` in a format identical to that of `X` or `Y` from the code above. How can I obtain the chi square function value in this way?

**EDIT:**

If I change the function `get_grid_data` to `get_grid_params` and redefine `get_grid_data` as is done below, I can generate 81 values of chi square. I think this is a step forward, but I'm not sure about the order of the array elements in `res` (aka `Z` above) necessary for the contour plot.

```
def get_grid_params(distribution, frac, size):
    """
    This function returns the grid values for a contour plot of the
    error metric as a function of the parameters of a specified
    distribution.

    EX:
        func:   'chi square', 'maximum log-likelihood' (error metric)
    """
    if distribution == 'gauss':
        opt_params = params_gauss
    a_vals = get_axis_data(opt_params[0], frac, size)
    b_vals = get_axis_data(opt_params[1], frac, size)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(a_vals, b_vals)
    # func = np.vectorize(func)
    # Z = func(distribution, [X, Y])
    return X, Y

def get_grid_data(distribution, frac=1/4, size=9, func=get_chi_square):
    """

    """
    X, Y = get_grid_params(distribution, frac, size)
    res = []
    for idx in range(len(X)):
        for jdx in range(len(Y)):
            res.append(func(distribution, [X[idx][jdx], Y[idx][jdx]])[0])
    print(res)
get_grid_data('gauss')
```

This prints

```
# 81 elements ==> 9x9 grid
[4208765217.1232886, 79756867.433148235, 2102012.2187297232, 77845.812346977109, 4299.2223157168837, 2529.7286507333743, 20486.858965000847, 257923.37090704756, 4854102.2912357552, 93281349.868633255, 3214630.1060019895, 149308.23999474355, 9526.0996064385563, 892.28204593366377, 1078.7222202890009, 6755.3095776326609, 53291.09528539874, 588864.18413363863, 4691132.998034155, 266721.46912966535, 20459.717521392733, 2093.3255539124393, 279.78284725132187, 577.3737260040574, 3111.9705345888774, 17462.38755758019, 125880.4188491786, 450519.22715869371, 40667.241172187212, 5020.7992346344054, 744.8798302729781, 116.9962855442742, 364.63898596547921, 1791.3456214870084, 7916.7426067634342, 40972.313769493878, 76104.092836489493, 10798.249475713539, 2013.1185415524558, 381.52353083113587, 66.126519584745949, 264.93942984225561, 1200.5798834763946, 4482.867919608283, 18107.837200860213, 21572.225934943446, 4551.094178016996, 1136.7099239043926, 253.51850353558262, 54.455759914884304, 218.13425049819415, 897.03841272531849, 2952.9334085022683, 9936.4277408736034, 9337.1516297669732, 2622.2698023608255, 789.26686546629082, 202.78664001629076, 60.365012999827258, 199.40257099587109, 726.84333101567586, 2159.6632005396755, 6339.5377293121628, 5372.7483380962221, 1815.8139713332946, 620.16531689499118, 184.61780691354744, 75.563465535153725, 196.96163816097214, 626.64757117448494, 1701.8233311097256, 4494.3117008380068, 3664.4699687203392, 1400.0096023072927, 527.65588603959168, 182.94718825996048, 96.20249715692033, 204.59025315045054, 566.75361531867895, 1416.8609878368447, 3434.8994517014899]
# reshape as 9x9 shows the order of params is wrong.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the code above until (but including) the section where `get_chi_square` is defined with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252532/how-can-i-efficiently-generate-a-dim-2-array-of-a-non-vectorizable-function) produces [the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N8Zk.png).