# How do I use numpy to vectorise chi squared calculations over a 2D grid?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, chi-squared

I have some data consisting of 3 1-dimensional arrays of length `N`: `x`, `y`, `y_errors`, which I am modelling with `A*sin(w*x+phi)+c`. I have defined a chi-squared function and used `scipy.optimise.minimise` to fit the model to the data. I would now like to consider a discrete 2-dimensional grid ranging over some set of values of any 2 parameters from `A`,`w`,`phi`,`c` e.g. I might want to consider the grid of values where `A` ranges over `[0,1,2,3]` and `w` ranges over `[0.2,0.3,0.4]`. I would like to calculate the value of chi-squared for each pair of values on the grid (using fixed values for  the parameters not spanned by the grid i.e. `phi` and `c` in the example).

This can easily be achieved using for loops, but this is quite inefficient. I would like to find a faster way to do the calculations. I am open to other ideas, but the most obvious solution seems to be to vectorise the problem using numpy arrays. My question is: how do I most efficiently (and ideally straightforwardly) compute all the chi-squared values on the grid (using numpy to vectorise the equations)?

There are similar questions to this on stack exchange e.g. [Loopless chi-square grid search in Python numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224765/loopless-chi-square-grid-search-in-python-numpy) and [How can I vectorize this specific non-numpy function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070902/how-can-i-vectorize-this-specific-non-numpy-function), however the answers do not seem to be very assertive about giving the best/most efficient or 'correct' approach. The problem I am trying to solve is a **very common and important task for data analysis in the physical sciences** (several hundred undergraduates at my university alone would appreciate a solution), so I think it is worth getting a clear and definitive answer in the context of this example which I think serves as a good typical set-up for this type of problem.

I have tried to tackle the problem myself, but I encounter difficulties in casting the arrays together. My approach is to make a numpy meshgrid for the 2D grid of the variable parameters (e.g. `A` and `w`), then I store these alongside the constant parameters (e.g. `phi` and `c`) in a list, which I turn into a numpy array, and this array of parameters is supplied to chi-squared and hence the model function in order to do the chi-squared calculations (I have also tried making numpy arrays of the same shape as each array in the meshgrid filled with the constant values of the remaining 2 parameters - this is commented out in my code). The problem I encounter is that when it comes to calculating chi-squared, this needs to iterate over all of the data points in the arrays `x`, `y`, `y_errors` as well as to iterate over all the different parameter values in the meshgrid. Trying to do this causes a numpy casting error.

I will include the relevant parts of my code below for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.stats as stats

#TEST DATA
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)
y=np.sin(x)+np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.01,size=len(x))
y_error=np.array([0.01]*len(x))

#MODEL
def sinusoidal_model(t,params):
    A,w,phi,c=params
    return(A*np.sin(w*t+phi)+c)

#CHI-SQUARED
def chi_squared(model_params, model, x, y, y_error):
    return np.sum(((y - model(x, model_params))/y_error)**2)

#INITIAL MODEL PARAMETERS
A=1
w=1
phi=0
c=0
initial_params=np.array((A,w,phi,c))

#FITTING
model=sinusoidal_model
deg_freedom = x.size - initial_params.size 
fit = opt.minimize(chi_squared, initial_params, args=(model, x, y, y_error))
fit_params= fit.x
chisq_min = chi_squared(fit_params, model, x, y, y_error)

#GENERATE COLOUR AND CONTOUR PLOTS
i_of_param_i=0
j_of_param_j=1
param_i=fit_params[i_of_param_i]
param_j=fit_params[j_of_param_j]
param_i_half_range=1
param_j_half_range=1
n_points_x=5
n_points_y=4
param_i_axis=np.linspace(param_i-param_i_half_range,param_i+param_i_half_range,n_points_x)
param_j_axis=np.linspace(param_j-param_j_half_range,param_j+param_j_half_range,n_points_y)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(param_i_axis,param_j_axis,indexing='xy')
"""
grid_shape=X.shape
parameters=[np.full(grid_shape,fit_params[i]) for i in range(len(fit_params))]
parameters[i_of_param_i]=X
parameters[j_of_param_j]=Y
parameters=np.array(parameters)
x=np.full(grid_shape,x)
y=np.full(grid_shape,y)
y_error=np.full(grid_shape,y_error)
Z=chi_squared(parameters, model, x, y, y_error)
"""
parameters=list(np.array(param) for param in list(fit_params))
parameters[i_of_param_i]=X
parameters[j_of_param_j]=Y
parameters=np.array(parameters)
Z=chi_squared(parameters, model, x, y, y_error)
```

Note that the first few lines of the "GENERATE COLOUR AND CONTOUR PLOTS" section are just there so that I can easily switch which parameters a I want to hold constant and which I want to vary over the grid.

Summary: I want to make a chi-squared surface plot for a model over some 2D parameter space with any other parameters held fixed. The issue is that chi-squared must take in the data and the range of parameters on which to calculate chi-squared, but these have different dimensions and can't be cast against each other.

Comment: What about not doing it yourself and let a (probably optimized) Python module do the work for you? See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html

Comment: First, vectorized operations on numpy arrays work if the *number* of dimensions of your arrays are the same, even if the actual shapes are different. You can use `np.expand_dims` or `np.reshape` to pad your arrays with the extra dimensions they need. Second, I'd just use loops anyway. None of the `scipy.optimize` stuff works for multidimensional parameters (you could *maybe* find a way to use `least_squares` and flattening and slicing). Maybe consider using `curve_fit` directly? You can also speed things up marginally by giving the jacobian directly, explicitly importing `sin` and `sqrt`, etc